# How would I be able to compare 2 sets of JSON data and check if one is in the other

Tags: json, python-3.x, roblox

So I am coding a Discord bot using Python that gets the data from Roblox's API to check if a user is in a allied group. So I made a loop to find if the user is in the same group but it does not work as intended. When I was testing it, it would say I was not in the group even though I was. I received no errors when running this code:

````py
for x in data:
                num = data.index(x)
                if data[num]["Name"] == "ΒΕ • British Empire":
                    print("its bigs squad")
                    print(data[num]["Role"])
                    bruh = str(data[num]["Role"])




                    dat = requests.get("https://api.roblox.com/groups/8616457/allies")
                    date = dat.json()['Groups']
                    groups = list(date)

                    for f in groups:
                        e = groups.index(f)
                        print(e)
                        if data[num]['Name'] == groups[e]['Name']:
                            print("in group")
                            member = ctx.author
                            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=bruh)
                            await member.add_roles(role)
                            await ctx.send(f"Gave the **{bruh}** role!") #fix
                        else:
                            print("not in group")```

###JSON data I am comparing


{"Groups":[{"Name":"ΒΕ • Administration","Id":8664914,"Owner":{"Name":"EA6Y","Id":100403322},"EmblemUrl":"http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=6109292568","Description":" & \n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n\nThe Development & Administration team include developers, administrators, and moderators that keep the group running smoothly, in-game, and in the communication servers."```

###Also comparing this one


[{"Name":"Roblox","Id":7,"EmblemUrl":"http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=607941191","EmblemId":607941191,"Rank":255,"Role":"Owner","IsPrimary":false,"IsInClan":false},{"Name":"Roblox Wiki","Id":127081,"EmblemUrl":"http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=607954721","EmblemId":607954721,"Rank":254,"Role":"Wiki System Operator","IsPrimary":false,"IsInClan":false}]
````

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a sample of the json you're looking for and a sample of the response you might get from the http request?

Comment: Just added a sample of both I am trying to compare.